# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' while updating targetSdkVersion from 30 to 31

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, javac, android-api-31

I am migrating targetSdkVersion from API 30 to 31. Gradle wrapper version using is distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip. Gradle tool version is classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4' and buildToolsVersion is 28.0.3. Jdk version i am using is 1.8.

When i am trying to change only targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 31 i get below error in one of my project's module and i am not able to build my project.

```
Execution failed for task ':billing:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I have been stuck at this and not getting how to move forward. Is there anything that i am missing when upgrading to API 31 ?